# Max query with where clause and having

Tags: mysql, having

```
SELECT * 
FROM   `3g_t2_24hour_data` 
WHERE  `start time` = '2013-12-08' 
       AND `bsc6900ucell` = 'SYZIN9WA' 
HAVING `vs.hsdpa.meanchthroughput.totalbytes (byte)` = max( 
       `vs.hsdpa.meanchthroughput.totalbytes (byte)`)
```

The above query giving no result. but there are 24 values for object SYZIN9WA in 2013-12-08. this query should give result of all field where `VS.HSDPA.MeanChThroughput.TotalBytes (byte)` is maximum.

Comment: It's hard to answer this question without knowing what's in the database itself.

Answer (score 2):

You should use Group BY with having cluase:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   `3g_t2_24hour_data` 
WHERE  `start time` = '2013-12-08' 
   AND `bsc6900ucell` = 'SYZIN9WA' 
GROUP BY `start time`
HAVING `vs.hsdpa.meanchthroughput.totalbytes (byte)` = max( 
   `vs.hsdpa.meanchthroughput.totalbytes (byte)`)
```

I hope it work prefect.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

Comment: This query is incorrect.  You are mixing "hidden columns" and aggregation results in the `having` clause.

Comment: I just make example as mojibul example for accustoming him with having clause.

Answer (score 0):

It is so complicated Table name and column names....

> *"The above query giving no result.*"

I don't think so. Columns without Aggregation function can't specified in HAVING clause.

> *" there are 24 values for object SYZIN9WA in 2013-12-08. This query should give result of all field where VS.HSDPA.MeanChThroughput.TotalBytes (byte) is maximum."*

If you are want max value in 24 records, it's simple.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   `3g_t2_24hour_data` 
WHERE  `start time` = '2013-12-08' 
       AND `bsc6900ucell` = 'SYZIN9WA' 
ORDER BY `vs.hsdpa.meanchthroughput.totalbytes (byte)` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

But if you are trying to find which row has max value of whole data set, little bit complicated JOIN is needed as follows.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM   `3g_t2_24hour_data` t1 INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT MAX(`vs.hsdpa.meanchthroughput.totalbytes (byte)`) AS mx
    FROM `3g_t2_24hour_data`
) t2 ON t1.`vs.hsdpa.meanchthroughput.totalbytes (byte)` = t2.mx
WHERE  t1.`start time` = '2013-12-08' 
       AND t1.`bsc6900ucell` = 'SYZIN9WA'
```

### UPDATE

> *"your first query is ok for one object (like bsc6900ucell = 'SYZIN9WA'). if i remove this condition, then how can i get similar result for all objects under field(bsc6900ucell)."*

Not sure I understand you comment well. could you try this?

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM   `3g_t2_24hour_data` t1 INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT `bsc6900ucell`,
        MAX(`vs.hsdpa.meanchthroughput.totalbytes (byte)`) AS mx
    FROM `3g_t2_24hour_data`
    GROUP BY `bsc6900ucell`
) t2 ON t1.`vs.hsdpa.meanchthroughput.totalbytes (byte)` = t2.mx
  AND t1.`bsc6900ucell` = t2.`bsc6900ucell`
WHERE  t1.`start time` = '2013-12-08' ;
```

Comment: actually, i need the result of all objects(field: `bsc6900ucell`) for a particular day from hourly data. result should show all values of row where `vs.hsdpa.meanchthroughput.totalbytes (byte)` is max within 24 hours data

Comment: @mojibul hello. co-relation sub-query and outer query have same `WHERE condition`. I wonder why you are doing this. If preceding query returns what you want, 1st query of mine is faster and easy to understand. Thanks.

Comment: @mojibul second, JOIN query (2nd query of mine) is faster than co-relation sub-query.

Comment: your first query is ok for one object (like `bsc6900ucell` = 'SYZIN9WA'). if i remove this condition, then how can i get similar result for all objects under field(`bsc6900ucell`). thanks

Comment: @mojibul I've updated. but not sure it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

A good way of thinking about this is to move the condition to the `where` clause.  You want to get the values that match the maximum (for the given conditions):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   `3g_t2_24hour_data` 
WHERE  `start time` = '2013-12-08' AND `bsc6900ucell` = 'SYZIN9WA' and
       `vs.hsdpa.meanchthroughput.totalbytes (byte)` =
           (select max( `vs.hsdpa.meanchthroughput.totalbytes (byte))
            from 3g_t2_24hour_data
            where `start time` = '2013-12-08' AND `bsc6900ucell` = 'SYZIN9WA'
           );
```

Note that you need to repeat the `where` conditions in the subquery to get what you want.

As for performance.  MySQL does a pretty good job optimizing subqueries after an `=` sign.  The most recent versions of MySQL does well with `in` as well, although this is a recent optimization.  Older versions implement `in` followed by a subquery very inefficiently.

If performance is an issue, just an an index:  `3g_t2_24hour_data(bsc6900ucell, "start time")`.

Finally, your original use of the `having` clause does make some sense conceptually (in other words, this is a common mistake).  However, that is not how SQL is defined.  In almost all SQL engines, this query would generate an error because the column with the long name is not in a `group by` clause.  MySQL allows this, but it fills in an arbitrary value from a single row for the comparison -- and that is not what you want.

EDIT (in response to comment):

Make the subquery a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   `3g_t2_24hour_data` t1
WHERE  `start time` = '2013-12-08' and
       `vs.hsdpa.meanchthroughput.totalbytes (byte)` =
           (select max( `vs.hsdpa.meanchthroughput.totalbytes (byte))
            from 3g_t2_24hour_data t2
            where `start time` = '2013-12-08' AND t1.`bsc6900ucell` = t2.`bsc6900ucell`
           );
```

Comment: i found the exact code you mentioned here and this is giving my desired result. but, this query will give result only for one object under `bsc6900ucell`. if i want the same result for all objects under `bsc6900ucell`, i.e for each object similar max result, what should be the modification in the above code???. thanks